# Get List of values Macro Container Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have added a Macro Container into my page. Now in the CMS I selected all the Macro's that I wished to be added to the Macro Container field as shown below

[image]

Now I'm fairly new in C# and Umbraco I was thinking of retrieving the value using the below code

```
foreach (var m in node.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<Object>>("macro")) {
     var n = m;
}
```

Now I thought it will display in an Array or List form but somehow I got a string of all the content of the Macro's I added

[image]

Any idea on how to retrieve those in a list? I'm thinking of looping through all those item to be displayed in my cshtml file. Really appreciate your help on this one.

Update:
This is the component of the Macro I used

[image]
[image]

Update V2:
[image]

The approach I was using was to specify the actual name of the Macro. Like `@Umbraco.RenderMacro("StockistStoreLocatorPartial")` but what I want is more dynamic like what if the name of the macro comes from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you share your document type with us? Or what is the data type of this "Macro"?

Besides, I wonder if [this](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Templating/Macros/) would fit what you need.

Comment: Your Macro Container looks like a custom data type to me as I could not find it in the default data type in both Umbraco 7 and Umbraco 8. Any way

Comment: Anyway, what does `node.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<Object>>("macro")` give you? Usually, this <Object> should a strong-typed data type rather than a generic one, for example, `Model.Value<IEnumerable<Link>>("footerLinks");` that's why I ask for your data type.

Comment: I tried the node.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<Object>>("macro") and it just gave me a null value

Comment: I am not sure what the "Marco Container" in your case, can you find it in the data type and take a screenshot? Are you using Umbraco 7 or 8? Besides, the recommended way to use Macros can be found [here](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Templating/Macros/index-v7).  So far, I feel like you may in the wrong track.

Comment: I have updated my question also I'm using Umbraco 7. The approach I was using was to specify the actual name of the Macro. Like  @Umbraco.RenderMacro("StockistStoreLocatorPartial") but what I want is more dynamic like what if the name of the macro comes from the list

Comment: Not sure which specific Umbraco 7 version you are in. The Label data type I found is not editable, it is interesting that you can add items to it like a select list. Anyway, base on what you said, I would suggest using a DropDown List with pre-setting the Macro's names, then loop through your list to render the Macro in code like @Umbraco.RenderMacro("<your macro name>")